# Merging two records together after Dissolve to get total number for combining both records using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dissolve

In ArcMap, I have two records for Eastbound ridership and Westbound ridership on a segment. I got this by dissolving according to the segment's unique ID. I'm left over with the 2 records showing EB and WB ridership numbers, but I only want 1 record.

Is there an automated way to combine both EB and WB ridership numbers together to just show total ridership for the segment?

Attributes:

```
ID, Direction, Segment ID, Ridership Numbers

1,       EB,          0001,             45

2,       WB,          0001,             61

3,       NB,          0002,             20

4,       SB,          0002,             22

5,       EB,          0003,             57

6,       WB,          0003,             71
```

Dissolved on Segment ID for Segment 0001.

Resulting Table:

```
ID, Segment ID, Ridership Numbers

1,       0001,             45

2,       0001,             61
```

I need to combine the above into one record like this:

ID, Segment ID, Ridership Numbers

```
1,       0001,             106
```

Comment: The Dissolve tool includes a 'Statistics Field(s)' designator, which includes a 'Sum' option.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Running that command is how we got the two records in the first place. Do you have any other ideas how to take that result and combine them together into one?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to describe the attributes of the feature class, the parameters provided to the Dissolve utility, and the resulting table, using a two or three line sample table.

Comment: How are you getting *any* `Ridership Numbers` if you dissolve on `Segment ID`?  Through a Join, perhaps?  What if you specify `Sum(Ridership Numbers)` in the Dissolve?

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:

1) Use 'Find Identical' (from Data Management Tools -> General);

2) Join the result of p.1 with your original table by system ObjectID field;

3) In Model Builder: 'Insert -> Iterators -> For' and set 'From Value' and 'To Value' the min and max values from the 'FEAT_SEQ' field of your table (after p.2);

4) Use 'Select Layer By Attribute' from 'Data Management Tools -> Layers and Table Views' in your Model. Here 'test_table' must been your table after p.2 and %Value% is loop variable.
[image]

5)Next for selected rows you can try apply some approach from next link:
https://community.esri.com/thread/173281
I think for your case is better the last approach (from Hornbydd user);

6) In finish after use this model you need to doing Dissolve by your 'Segment ID' field.

*** Sorry for my English